# Translate string

Tags: localisation

We bought a theme and installed our local language files.

We are missing the translation of a line:  $title = __('Products you might like!')

Its located in app/code/THEMENAME/AjaxCart/Block/Ui/Related.php

How do I figure out, what da_dk.xxx.xx.xx.csv file + what I should call the line in the csv file:

"Products you might like!", "Produkter du måske man slide!", x, y ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

language csv file name should be EN_us.csv or SV_se.csv format. Language code with country code. You can put the csv file in app/design/theme/i18n location.
you can ommit x, y column in csv.

Comment: But how do I identify the x + y (ie. module,Magento_CatalogRule or module,Magento_CatalogSearch or something entirely different)

Comment: No problem this csv file apply as global frontend. If you want to use as module individual like including x,y column then add a language package to app/i18n. check magento doc fir details.